# drupal view2 views_query_alter for JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

i'm trying to alter drupal view-2 query, basically want to add one more table. I'm able to alter the where clause of query using hook_views_query_alter() but don't know how to join one more table.

```
function module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
        if ($view->name == 'view1_name') {
                $query->where[0]['args'][] = 'SOMETEXT';
                $query->where[0]['clauses'][] = "QUERY";
        }

        if($view->name = 'view2_name'){
              $query->table_queue['content_type_sold_product'];
              $query->tables['content_type_sold_product'];
        }
    }
```

Why do i want to do this - if relationship tab is available in view that is used to join the table, but in my case table which i want to join contains the field that is not a node-reference however field name and its value matches with one of the view table table.

Does anyone know how to perform JOIN in views_query_alter().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Giving Answer to own question**

fortunately i found these links

http://drupalmodules.com/module/reverse-node-reference module enhances views with reverse relationships for node reference fields.

you may also need http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships

Answer (score 2):

Seems there are two different ways you can do this, see these links:

[Adding a JOIN statement in hook_views_query_alter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134941/adding-a-join-statement-in-hook-views-query-alter)

[Add Table Join, Where, and Order By to Views Query in views_query_alter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851945/add-table-join-where-and-order-by-to-views-query-in-views-query-alter)